# Integral with theta function

Tags: integration, theta-functions

$$I=\int_{-L/2}^{L/2}dx \Theta(\epsilon-2A|x|)$$  $L>0; A>0$ and $\epsilon$ are parameters, I should solve this integral but I don't know how I thought about solving it like this:
$$\epsilon-2A|x|>0$$ so that $$\epsilon>2A|x|$$ but from here on I don't know how to go on. These are the solutions of the integral reported in the book:

$I=\dfrac{2\pi mL\epsilon}{A}$ for $\epsilon\leq AL$

$I=2\pi mL^2$ for $\epsilon> AL$ where $h$ is Planck's constant.

The Heavyside $\Theta$ function is so defined:

$$
\Theta(x) =
  \begin{cases}
                                   1 & \text{ if } x \geq 0\\
                                   0 & \text{if } x < 0\\
  \end{cases}
$$

I hope you can help me.

Comment: **What** "theta function" is that? Jacobi's?

Comment: @DonAntonio Heaviside

Comment: I don't know how Placks constant $h$ should appear in the solution? Is it included in m?

Comment: Oh, the good'ol Heavyside steps function. Ok.

Comment: SOrry guys, my bad, no Planck's constant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a good start.
\begin{align}
\theta(\epsilon-2A|x|) = 1 \quad&\Longleftrightarrow\quad
\epsilon-2A|x| \ge 0
\\ &\Longleftrightarrow\quad
\epsilon \ge 2A|x|
\\ &\Longleftrightarrow\quad
|x| \le \frac{\epsilon}{2A}
\end{align}
So, if $\frac{\epsilon}{2A} \ge \frac{L}{2}$, then
$$
I = \int_{-L/2}^{L/2} 1\;dx = L
$$
on the other hand, if $\frac{\epsilon}{2A} < \frac{L}{2}$, then
$$
I = \int_{-\epsilon/(2A)}^{\epsilon/(2A)} 1\;dx = \frac{\epsilon}{A}
$$
Of course, my condition $\frac{\epsilon}{2A} \ge \frac{L}{2}$ is
the same as your condition $\epsilon \ge AL$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

Split the integral into positive $x$ and negative $x$

$$I=\int_{-L/2}^{L/2}dx \theta(\epsilon-2A|x|)=\int_{-L/2}^0dx \theta(\epsilon-2A|x|) +\int_{0}^{L/2}dx \theta(\epsilon-2A|x|)$$
$$=\int_{-L/2}^0dx \theta(\epsilon+2Ax) +\int_{0}^{L/2}dx \theta(\epsilon-2Ax).$$

Now, split the integrals such that the Heavyside theta function is well separated.